# How to create custom channel binder for publishing RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent?

Tags: spring-cloud-config

It seems like spring-cloud-config-monitor has strong dependency on spring-cloud-bus to publish RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent to config-server clients. What is good way to break that dependency? I would like to use something custom to distribute that events over to client applications.

One way would be for me to create custom channel implementation that can create appropriate beans to support the configuration. I looked at *ChannelBindingServiceConfiguration* but it was not very clear to me how to achieve this. I haven't used spring-cloud-bus so its seems rather involved. Any quick guide someone can point me to?

Are there any other alternate approaches?

Comment: @DaveSayer: Any insights?